# How to show image and content from the database to a PHP page?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I want to show image and content together on the page using php. I am able to show only image to a page using php by the setting the header(“Content-type: image/png”); but unable to show it along with the html content that fetched from database.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: you can't send both in the same response, unless you embed the image in the html as a data-uri

Answer (score -1):

You can not have the same code for this in one file. You have to make a minimum of 2 files. one to create the image and one to display the html.

**image.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
// read a file or create it using GD below:
readfile("/path/to/image.png");
```

Next you want to make your html:

**page.php**

```
<p>
    <img src="image.php" alt="my image" />
</p>
<p>
    Here some HTML alongside my php image!
</p>
```

Comment: this will not work when both the things coming in the same query and we have to send them together. But using data-uri we can do this.